# Make a program that does union of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have to make a program that gives as a result the union of two lists using a `For` loop. I can't figure out how to inspect if the elements of a list are different. Any help?

Comment: Have you seen the function `Union`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm not late to this fun-filled party of *disfunctional*-programming!

```
unionFor[list1_, list2_] := 
 Module[{lista = {list1[[1]]}, listb = {list2[[1]]}, list, i, j},
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[list1], i++,
   For[j = 1, j <= Length[lista], j++,
     If[list1[[i]] == lista[[j]], Break[]];
     If[j >= Length[lista], AppendTo[lista, list1[[i]]]]
     ];
   ];
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[list2], i++,
   For[j = 1, j <= Length[listb], j++,
     If[list2[[i]] == listb[[j]], Break[]];
     If[j >= Length[listb], AppendTo[listb, list2[[i]]]]
     ];
   ];
  list = lista;
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[listb], i++,
   For[j = 1, j <= Length[lista], j++,
     If[listb[[i]] == lista[[j]], Break[]];
     If[j == Length[lista], AppendTo[list, listb[[i]]]];
     ];
   ]; list]

list1 = RandomInteger[10, 5]
list2 = RandomInteger[10, 5]

(*{3, 8, 4, 3, 7}*)
(*{9, 10, 5, 4, 9}*)

unionFor[list1, list2]
(*{3, 8, 4, 7, 9, 10, 5}*)
```

**EDIT** explanation of the code

There's three double-nested `For` loops here. The first two are identical and serve to delete the duplicates from the inputted lists. The last one takes the second list, takes its element and then cycles over the first list to see if it also has that element. If a match is found it `Break[]`'s the execution of the inner `For` loop and continues on to the next element of the second list. If no match is found, no `Break` happens and the counter `j` eventually reaches its maximum value which is equal to the length of the first list. If that (`j==Lengt[lista]`) happens, the element being tested for possible matches is `AppendTo`-ed the output list.

Comment: How does the last for loop work?

Comment: The explanation is a bit long-winded, so I've added it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: Admittedly, this answer was put together offhand for the lulz, so even as far as iterative loops go, it's quite a bad example. For instance, it will break if given empty lists as input and there are surely several better ways to do this with `For` loops. One idea that comes to mind and would give the same result is `Join[list1,list2]` then delete the duplicates from that list using the same procedure as in my answer.

Comment: This can be done with two sets of loops. Not sure why you needed three. Its still so ugly I'm not going to post it though

Comment: As I said, it's doable in one loop too. Depends on the restrictions imposed by the task. I came up with three loops to be more or less symmetric wrt each of the lists - delete duplicates from one (that's one loop), from the next (that's two), add elements from one list to the other, checking for repeats - three. With a bit of thought outside the box there's always room for improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a for loop, you may consider `Union` straight away:

```
Union[RandomInteger[10, 3], RandomInteger[10, 3]]
    (*{0, 4, 6, 9, 10}  Obviously result will different for each run *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are doing this as a programming exercise otherwise you would use [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html).

To perform a manual union you might consider using a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to locate and [`Insert`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Insert.html) items in a list.  However as *Mathematica* lists are implemented as arrays this is doomed to have poor computational complexity unless you compile it.  A rudimentary example:

```
(* your input lists *)
a = {3, 0, 1, 4};
b = {5, 1, 2, 0};


Needs["Combinatorica`"]

in = Join[a, b];     (* concatenate all input lists *)
out = {First[in]};

Do[
 p = BinarySearch[out, x];
 If[! IntegerQ[p], out = Insert[out, x, ⌈p⌉] ],
 {x, in}
]

out
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

Comment: Ahh, sorry I misread, I will delete :P

Answer (score 1):

Done in utterly non-functional style 80's Basic-ish:

```
union[lst1_, lst2_] := 
 Module[{res = {}, lists = Join[lst1, lst2], member},

  member[lst_, mem_] := (For[k = 1, k <= Length@lst, k++,
     If[lst[[k]] === mem, Return[True]]]; False);

  For[j = 1, j <= Length@lists, j++,
   If[member[res, lists[[j]]], Continue[], AppendTo[res, lists[[j]]]]];
  res]
```

Comment: Some people are so used to functional programming, that even their iterative loops look like functional programming...